# Request timeout DJANGO API when uploading files, even if the file is 1 pixel only

Tags: python, django, rest, android-studio, request

I am working on a Android Studio app, and I am having trouble uploading images from the app to my host using my DJANGO API.
This is literally my endpoint:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def changeProfile(request):
    user_id = int(request.data.get('userId', ''))

    pfp_file = request.FILES.get('pfp', None)
    pfb_file = request.FILES.get('pfb', None)
    
    data = {'rescode': '0001', 'message': 'Profile updated'}

    # Set CORS headers
    response = Response(data)
    response = Response(data)
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'content-type'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS'
    
    return response
```

I have made the request from Postman, from the android app even from a js file in the same directory as the API. All had the request "pending" and after 2 minutes it just gave error 500 timeout. It isn't due to the file size cause I even tried with a 1 by 1 image and it still had the same problem. It is also not lack of host resources like RAM or CPU cause I have checked them while the request was pending and it just stayed the same. And the weirdest part is that neither the client or server side have errors on the logs.

Answer (score 0):

This may relate to the way you are *serving* your Django app. You may not have enough processes or threads to serve all the incoming requests.  You don't need a lot of traffic to see such a thing happen.  It could easily happen locally during testing...

Do you perhaps have other parts of that same page which have resources which do take a long time to download? Do you maybe have requests that are blocked accessing external resources or running very long DB queries?

By default, depending on the version of Django you are using, the development server in Django may be single-threaded.

I think this would explain all of your symptoms.